# MS Access - Union a two SELECT statements with one statement containing Aggregate function

Tags: ms-access, select, union, aggregate-functions, ms-access-2016

Let's say I have this table of data, [Table]:

```
[ColumnA] [ColumnB]
 Field1      10
 Field2      20
 Field3      30
 Field4      40
 Field5      50
```

I have two SELECT statements. One is to select a range of fields to show:

`SELECT * FROM [Table];`

Another one is to calculate the Standard Deviation and Average of these fields:

`SELECT StDev([ColumnB]) AS [Standard Deviation], Avg([ColumnB]) AS [Average] FROM [Table];`

Is there a way to union these two queries together, or if possible, in one single query?

So the end result will look like:

```
[ColumnA] [ColumnB] [Standard Deviation] [Average]
 Field1      10             XX              YY
 Field2      20             XX              YY            
 Field3      30             XX              YY
 Field4      40             XX              YY
 Field5      50             XX              YY
```

However, I know that from the first query, it will show a total of 5 row records. But from the second query, it will only show a single row record. In this case, is it possible to indicate the same results in the [Standard Deviation] and [Average] columns? So when I plot a graph based on these data, it will show as a series of points that can be connected in a horizontal straight line.

Not sure if the explanation suffices.
Please help.

Comment: Are the stdDev &  average of the entire table or based on another column?

Comment: @ClintB StDev and Avg are based on [ColumnB].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If second query returns just one row, you can use query like this:

```
SELECT TABLE.ColumnA
    ,TABLE.ColumnB
    ,[Standard Deviation]
    ,[Average]
FROM [Table]
    ,(
        SELECT StDev([ColumnB]) AS [Standard Deviation]
            ,Avg([ColumnB]) AS [Average]
        FROM [Table]
        );
```

Comment: Will there be an error if first query returns five rows, and second query returns only one row? Does this mean that the remaining 4 rows are empty?

Comment: No, this is not an error. Here we make full join of two sources, it will produce #_Rows_In_Source1 * #_Rows_In_Source2 rows, in your case 5 * 1=5 rows, all rows will be with data, as requested.

Comment: If I want to apply a WHERE clause in both first and second queries, how can I do it? Should I do something like this? `SELECT TABLE.ColumnA, TABLE.ColumnB, [Standard Deviation], [Average] FROM [Table] WHERE [ColumnB] > 10, (SELECT StDev([ColumnB]) AS [Standard Deviation], Avg([ColumnB]) AS [Average] FROM [Table] WHERE [ColumnB] > 10);`

Comment: Yes, that's right, you have to add condition to both queries